# Having infinite loop because scanf() does not stop the program to take entry from user

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, infinite-loop, stdio

I need to write a program which calculates fibonacci sequence but I stuck because of this infinite loop.

When I enter -5 it prints Please enter "positive" term(s) number:.

Then I enter "a" and it prints Please enter "numeric" term(s) number: infinitely.

I couldn't figure out why it is. Thanks for any help.

(note : I tried to use fflush(stdin) but didn't fix this. I thought maybe \n char left in the stdin buffer.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calculate_fibonacci_sequence(){
        int n,is_entry_valid;
        int flag = 0;
        printf("Please enter term(s) number : ");
        while(!flag){
                is_entry_valid = scanf("%d",&n);
                if(is_entry_valid == 1){
                        if(n > 0){
                                flag = 1;
                        }else{
                                printf("Please enter \"positive\" term(s) number: ");
                        }
                }else{
                        printf("Please enter \"numeric\" term(s) number: ");
                }
        }
}

int main(){
        calculate_fibonacci_sequence();
        return(0);
}
```

Comment: In the `else{ printf("Please enter \"numeric\" term(s) number: "); }` block, add code the reads the offending non-integer input, like `scanf("%*s");`.

Comment: thanks to you now I understand why it is and scanf("%*s"); fix this. But still I am confused about why fflush(stdin) can't remove 'a' from the input stream.

Comment: @BaranSAHİN: `fflush` is not defined for input streams.  A few implementations such as MSVC do implement `fflush( stdin )` to clear out all input, but that's specific to the implementation; it's not standard behavior and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, then read characters up to the next non-digit character; that non-digit character is left in the input stream.  Without a call to `getchar` or `fgetc` or similar, that character will not be removed.

So in the `else` branch of your `if (is_entry_valid == 1)` statement, you'll need to add something like

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' )
  ; // empty loop
```

which will remove everything up to and including the newline from the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` can be used to read a line then parse the line with `sscanf`.
In the case of non-integer input, the problem input has been removed by `fgets` so trying again for acceptable input is easy to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calculate_fibonacci_sequence(){
    char line[100] = "";
    int n,is_entry_valid;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Please enter term(s) number : ");
    while(!flag){
        fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin);
        is_entry_valid = sscanf(line, "%d",&n);
        if(is_entry_valid == 1){
            if(n > 0){
                flag = 1;
            }else{
                printf("Please enter \"positive\" term(s) number: ");
            }
        }else{
            printf("Please enter \"numeric\" term(s) number: ");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    calculate_fibonacci_sequence();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush `stdin` when you get a bad user input in order to clean the input buffer, this code should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculate_fibonacci_sequence(void)
{
    int n, is_entry_valid;
    int flag = 0;

    printf("Please enter term(s) number : ");
    while (!flag)
    {
        is_entry_valid = scanf("%d",&n);
        if (is_entry_valid == 1) {
            if (n > 0) {
                flag = 1;
            } else {
                printf("Please enter \"positive\" term(s) number: ");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Please enter \"numeric\" term(s) number: ");

            int c;
            // Flush stdin
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    calculate_fibonacci_sequence();
    return(0);
}
```